# Handle a bunch of arbitrary literals using Groovy AST Transformation

Tags: groovy, compiler-construction, transformation, dsl, abstract-syntax-tree

I read a lot about AST Transformation these days and now I want to handle some arbitrary literals not known by groovy. The specific idea is to enable groovy handling plain sql.

If you write `select a from tab where b = 'x'` in GroovyConsole, the AST looks like this at some point

```
MethodCall - this.select(a).from(tab).where((b = x))
```

With some effort, it should be possible to turn this into a sql-statement.
So everything is fine as long as I don't use an asterisk.
If I write `select * from tab` no AST can be built (no matter what phase) and an error occures:

```
Unable to produce AST for this phase due to earlier compilation error:
startup failed:
script123.groovy: 1: expecting EOF, found 'tab' @ line1, column 15.
```

So here's the question:

How can I turn the asterisk into something processable?

Comment: Are you specifially looking for a AST transformation or are other approaches possible for you?

Comment: I'm looking for the AST way. But other approaches would be nice to know as well. In fact, first I tried to do it without AST transformation but it seemed to me that one can do this only using AST transformation.

Comment: I've never tried it out, but I believe your transformation would need to be applied at the CompilerPhase.PARSING phase, when the syntax is still being interpreted. http://groovy.codehaus.org/Compiler+Phase+Guide

Answer (score 0):

I tried to get the CST after parsing was done. But it's always null and I couldn't find out why.
But I found another approach:
http://java.dzone.com/articles/run-your-antlr-dsl-groovy